# How can I find the sum of each individual element in an array of long numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, sum, addition

This question will need to be answered in Javascript.

For example, I have an array of phone numbers:

```
var phoneNumbers = ['123-434-4455', '123-495-8475', '484-728-3456'];
```

The phone number at index 0 (123-434-4455) would be added as 1+2+3+4+3+4+4+4+5+5, totaling to 35.

I'm guessing this will involve some kind of loop (for loops, or the method .forEach), because I will need to do this for multiple phone numbers in an array that will probably be randomly generated by a computer, so length and amount will vary.

Also, I'm wondering if the hyphen will matter, in which case I have found `.replaceAll("-","");`.

I've researched some other methods on here that involve .split, .parsInt, .map, .toString, .reduce, .digitSum, and more. They seem pretty complicated, especially since I'm in a beginning course (however I'm totally new to programming - this is my first post btw). Also, I'd rather not post the full question because I really want to figure it out alone, but this is the part I'm most stuck on. Forgive me if this has been answered previously! Like I said...new to programming.

I also need to determine which phone number has the last largest sum of digits, and use a return statement to return the required phone number in its’ original form.

Comment: How do you want to output the results? As an array? Printing each one to the console?

Comment: Those phone numbers are really strings, right? A JavaScript number can't look like `123-434-4455`. You can use `.split("")` to split a string into an array of individual characters, and then iterate through that array and add up the characters that look like digits.

Comment: Good point, they're not even technically digits, they're strings, as the question has them in single quotes. Thanks for that.

Comment: This comes up at least once a week for this exercise. Do a search will find many many answers to it

Comment: I tried and found a few convoluted answers, maybe I wasn't searching right...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) array methods:

```
['123-434-4455', '123-495-8475', '484-728-3456'].map(function(str) {
  return str.split('').reduce(function(a,b) {
    return a + (+b || 0);
  }, 0);
}); // [ 35, 48, 51 ]
```

Some notes:

- `split('')` splits a string into an array of characters
- `+b` coerces `b` into a number, e.g. `"5"` to `5` and `"-"` to `NaN`.
- `+b || 0` will return `0` if `+b` is falsy (`0` or `NaN`), and `+b` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it:

```
var phoneNumbers = ["123-434-4455", "123-495-8475", "484-728-3456"];

for (var i=0; i<phoneNumbers.length; i++) {//For every phone number
    var total=0; //create a total variable
    var indNumbers = phoneNumbers[i].replace(/-/g, ""); //remove all dashes
    for (var j=0; j<indNumbers.length; j++) {//loop for all digits
        total+=parseFloat(indNumbers[j]);//add each digit to total
    }
    console.log(total);//do stuff with it here
}
```

All pretty standard javascript stuff. Only confusing bit I might have used is the `.replace` method - my parameter is `/-/g` which might look scary, but it's the equivalent of passing in `"-"` except it tells the function to replace ALL instances of the dash. If you do pass `"-"`, it only replaces the first instance.

If you're a beginner, the things in this code you'll want to learn about are `.replace`, `parseFloat` `for` loops, and accessing strings using square bracket notation.

Comment: This is similar to what I've previously seen. I'm going to try it out. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The code will work but make sure you understand it before using it, and then try to improve it - such as, what would happen if one of your phone numbers had a character that wasn't a number or a dash?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info btw, I'm definitely going to research all the methods you've used in the code, especially before I try to use them.

Comment: This may sound dumb, but can you explain the two variables you created in the for loop? How did you know to create a total variable and the indNumbers variable (why did you give it that name btw)?

Comment: `total` gets created every time the first for loop iterates, and is used to store a running total of the sum of the current phone numbers digits. I knew to create this because I needed somewhere to store this information for use later. `indNumbers` is created as the value of the current phone number, but without the dashes. There was no real logic to naming this, other than it being short of "individual numbers" because I was going to be adding the individual numbers up.

Comment: got it, that all makes sense! Thanks a bunch @millerbr.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var phoneNumbers = ["123-434-4455", "123-495-8475", "484-728-3456"];

function crossSum(arr, pos) {
  var sum = 0;
  var a = arr[pos].split("-").join("").split("");
  a.forEach(function(e, i) {
    sum += parseInt(a[i]);
  })
  return sum;
}

document.write(crossSum(phoneNumbers, 0));
```

This function will return the cross-sum of
your phone-number.

Just use `crossSum(phoneNumers, 0) // 0 is the fist number of phoneNumbers`.

This will return the crossSum.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on @millerbr answer. If you don't want to use `.replace` you can just use `parseInt`/`parseFloat` on every char, if it is not a number those functions returns `NaN` which can be checked with `isNaN()` function

```
var phoneNumbers = ["123-434-4455", "123-495-8475", "484-728-3456"];

for (var i=0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) { //For every phone number
    var total=0; //create a total variable
    for (var j=0; j < phoneNumbers.length; j++) { //loop for all digits
        var parsedNumber = parseInt(phoneNumbers[j]); // parse string to number or NaN if "-"
        if (!isNaN(parsedNumber)) { // Check if result is NaN (Not a Number).
          total += parsedNumber; //add each digit to total
        }
    }
    console.log(total);//do stuff with it here
}
```

Comment: Is there a big difference between parseInt/parseFloat? I suppose in this particular case they're interchangeable....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that phoneNumbers is an array of strings, you can indeed loop through the entire array and then in each element in the array you can loop through the string and check if the character is a number. If so, add it to your sum and then when you finish each element in the array you have the total sum for it and you can add it to another array full of your sums.

Comment: Correct, it is technically an array of strings. I will add quotes in the arrays. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I was wondering about this some more, and it brings up a good question. Yes, what if the person (or computer) entered an invalid key, like a letter or symbol. I think I'd have to somehow incorporate an if statement with NaN involved.